# Ethereum Puppeth private blockchain hosted in google cloud how to connect through rpc

Tags: go-ethereum, puppeth

I have deployed a priavate etheruem Poa bloackchain to google cloud using puppeth everything is working fine but i can't figure out how to connect throw rpc to the private network !

please help ! any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to launch geth with --rpc flag.

To allow external connections to your node (although it is not recommended for security reasons) you will also have to use --rpcaddr and --rpccorsdomain flags.

--rpcaddr is by default set on 127.0.0.1, so is --rpccorsdomain.

Comment: so you are saying that beside the sealnodes that i deployed using puppeth i have to deploy a new node with --rpcaddr <should i put the ip of the server am running the node in here ?> , how to connect this node to the rest of my deployed private blockchain . and thanks for your help my friend

Comment: TBH I thought puppeth was only useful to generate a custom genesis file ...
How do you launched your sealnodes ?
If you launched them by geth cli you would just have to enable --rpc flag and define --rpcaddr <the ip address from which you accept connexion, 0.0.0.0 for everyone> and --rpccorsdomain <same, "*" for everybody>

and if you want to use another node for rpc connexion you will need the genesis file and the enode :
geth init custom_genesis.json ;
geth --rpc console ;
(Now in geth console :)
admin.addPeer("enode")

Comment: i followed this article https://medium.com/@collin.cusce/using-puppeth-to-manually-create-an-ethereum-proof-of-authority-clique-network-on-aws-ae0d7c906cce to deploy a full blockchain using puppth now i am stuck cause i don't have rpc access to the blockchain i can't deploy my smart contract or connect a front end. if u have a link to guide how i use geth-cli to build poa network please recommend it to me am stuck. and thanks again

Comment: I read the tuto, at some point you get the genesis file and the enode of one of the node.
Can you try to init a new node with these ? geth init genesis.json && geth --networkid <your_network_id> --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" console; admin.addPeer("enode"). You can specify the network id when launching puppeth. PS: the enode should be the one of the bootnode, I think.